# How to call or acces a dataframe variables inside a funtion in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm struggling to create a function in R that uses data.frame's variable's names as part of its arguments.

Say for example that I have this data

```
test.df <- 
  data.frame(
    variable_1 = sample(letters[1:4],10, replace = T),
    variable_2 = rnorm(10,10,3),
    variable_3 = rnorm(10,40,15))
    
test.df
    
   variable_1 variable_2 variable_3
1           c   5.514034   59.23525
2           a  10.515690   31.94552
3           d  11.845118   47.39481
4           c   8.481335   22.32198
5           d   7.945798   29.02631
6           c   9.631182   41.90519
7           c   9.348816   53.79478
8           a   4.559642   58.47290
9           d   9.876674   53.53151
10          c  12.955443   49.84759
```

And I need to create a **function** which accesses any given variable by its name and, for example, extracts and reports it's mean in the form '`The mean is: X`' (where '`X`' contains the mean value). So far I've tried this:

```
my.function <- function(df, variable) {
  paste0("The mean is: ",
         round(mean(df$variable),2))
}
```

But when evaluating `my.function` in 'my test.df' it shows that is clearly doing the job:

```
> my.function(test.df, variable_2)
[1] "The mean of the varibale is: NA"
```

So my questions are:

- Hoy do I call variables names inside a funtion's argument? I know there is various ways to do this since outhere thare ere other libraries that for example uses either `variable_2` or `"variable_2"`, or when needing more than one variable, either list variables without quotations just separating them by commas (`variable_2, variable_3` as in `dplyr::select()`), or one has to place target variables as character groups (`c("variable_2", "variable_3")` as in `reshape2::melt()`)
- **BONUS**: I really like when using functions that require more than one variable, you can press **tab**, and the list of available variables shows up (as in `dplyr::select()` for example). How do I get this feature when building my own functions?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

If we are passing unquoted argument for column names, then convert to string with `deparse/substitute` and use `[[` instead of `$`.  Also, create a condition to check if the value from `substitute` is `symbol`, then use `deparse` so that it can pass both quoted and unquoted

```
my.function <- function(df, variable) {
 variable <- substitute(variable)
  if(is.symbol(variable)) variable <- deparse(variable)
   paste0("The mean is: ",
          round(mean(df[[variable]], na.rm = TRUE),2))
}
```

-testing

```
> my.function(test.df, variable_2)
[1] "The mean is: 9.86"
> my.function(test.df, "variable_2")
[1] "The mean is: 9.86"
```

---

If we want to get the mean of multiple columns, use `colMeans` and pass the variable as a character vector

```
my.function <- function(df, variable) {
    v1 <- colMeans(df[variable], na.rm = TRUE)
    sprintf("The mean of %s: %f", names(v1), v1)
    }
```

-testing

```
> my.function(test.df, c("variable_2", "variable_3"))
[1] "The mean of variable_2: 9.860057"  "The mean of variable_3: 42.317997"
```

Comment: Hi, do you known where to find documentation about this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `df$nameOfColumn`, you can use:

```
column <- "nameOfColumn"
df[[column]]
```

Example:

```
my.function <- function(df, variable) {
  paste0("The mean is: ",
         round(mean(df[[variable]]),2))
}
```

```
> my.function(test.df, "variable_2")
[1] "The mean is: 11.88"
```

This can be found in the R Language Definition under [Indexing](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Indexing)